# "Take something into account" vs "Take into account something" — are both correct?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, objects

Are the two usages both correct? Personally, I'd prefer

> take something into account

but I have heard some professors and academic textbook authors prefer

> take into account something.

Am I good to use what I prefer or the latter one is *more correct*?

Comment: The second one is incorrect.

Comment: "*taking* into account <something>", however, is prevalent. Eg. "Taking into account the rebound in the grey wolf population, ..."

Comment: @n00b I must disagree, at least in informal speech: *When planning your commute, you need to take into account the time of year as well as the time of day*.

Comment: Many dictionaries include phrases like this. For example: [*take someone or something into account* and *take into account someone or something*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+into+account+someone+or+something)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Take X into account" generally works better when X is not a lengthy expression. "Take into account X" generally works better when X is long enough that the reader might have lost the sense of "take" by the time "into account" rolls around. The less experienced the likely reader, the shorter the maximum length of X before it ought to appear after "into account" rather than before. The same is true of other idiomatic expressions constructed this way.

Comment: This sounds reasonable, and I came to the same conclusion as a non-native speaker.  However is such position officially upheld by grammaticians?